# Concat a dynamic sql query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm taking my first steps into developing dynamic sql queries and I've got a question for the forum. Can a concatenated select statement be appended with additional concatenated statements (see below code)?

```
use test;
drop procedure if exists test.spds;
delimiter $$
create procedure test.spds (
xage varchar(75),
xgender varchar(2),
xquery varchar(254))
begin
set @xan:= REPLACE(xage,'''','');
set @xgn:= REPLACE(xgender,'''','');

set xquery:=concat('select count(*) from test.ratings where quota=1')

if @xan is not null then
xquery:=xquery concat(' and age in (',@xan,')')

if @xgn is not null then
 xquery:=xquery concat(' and gender = ',@xgn,')

end if;

xquery=xquery concat(';');

prepare x1 from xquery;
execute x1;
deallocate prepare x1;

end if;
end $$
```

Again this is my first foray so maybe I'm approaching this all too simplistically and any guidance/suggestions would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes you can, try this

```
if @xan is not null then
   set xquery:=CONCAT(xquery, ' and age in (',@xan,')');
end if
```